# Apple In-App Purchase for answering quiz

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I have ben looking over and over in apples guidelines for In-app purchases but cant seem to find the answer.

Im making an app that has a weekly quiz presented to the user. What I want to do is charge the user for the answer he gives to the question with In-app purchase.

So my question is would it be ok to charge a person for an answer to a quiz according to apple? Any app out there that does this?

Thanks for any help!

A little clarification...
The user pays ex 70 cents to send his answer. He is then able to win prizes for example an iPad for the correct first prize answer.

EX. What day is US independence day?

Answer 1: 4 August
Answer 2: 4 June
Answer 3: 4 July
Answer 4: 5 July

(On iphone press the answer that is correct it costs 70 cents...)

The user pay for his answer and is then able to win prizes. Off course multiple users will have the same correct answer in this manner there will be a random selector of the first prize winner.

Comment: You want the user pay for the wrong answer ? Btw, interresting idea :))

Comment: Not only the wrong answer actually any answer. The user should be able to select an answer or type in his own and when he sends the answer he should be prompted to pay for it

Comment: Why would you want to pay for the answer? Is there a physical prize for the winner? I think more details are needed to properly answer this question

Comment: The user pays to "send an answer" and is then able to win prizes based upon his answer. If the user doesnt pay he isnt able to win.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Apple's rejection policies. See also: [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should worry about at least these two rules:

> 11.3  Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used outside of the application will be rejected
>
> 20.4  Apps that allow a user to directly purchase a lottery or raffle ticket in the app will be rejected

Comment: 20.4 Seems to hit it on the nail, surprised you haven't got the right answer tick already.

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb is in-app purchase works with electronic content only.  IF it's a physical real-world product or service you are out of luck.  As long as it doesn't fit into that category Apple seems happy to take 30% of whatever it is you can convince people to purchase.

Answer (score 0):

You need section 11 of the App Review Guidelines for iOS. [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html)
Based upon my reading, I think it will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this would probably get through, although it might be something that they decide on the day that they don't want in the store. From the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) linked by @Cameron:

> We will reject Apps for any content or behavior that we believe is
>   over the line. What line, you ask? Well, as a Supreme Court Justice
>   once said, "I'll know it when I see it". And we think that you will
>   also know it when you cross it.

An app that needs payment for an entry into a sweepstakes-style competition might sound a little too close to being spammy, but it might come across as totally legitimate. Up to how you present it, I suppose.

A consumable IAP would be what you're after here, with some in-app/server logic to work out whether the user has already answered that particular question (given that you're going to need server-side stuff to work out who has answered, who did it first, etc. etc.). This means that you won't need a new IAP product for each week, just the one quiz module. In your UI you can modify the question based the week, check if the user has already answered it, and if not allow them to purchase the consumable IAP product. Next week, same process, same product, different question presented to the user via info from your server.

Answer (score 0):

Thats gambling.  If Apple allowed that the whole app store would be penny auction apps.  not gonna fly.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer you use PayPal in your application, there will be no chance of application been rejected.

Hope it helps......